getting trello API authentication without a PowerUp
I want to make REST calls to trello to read information about the cards in my boards. If trello had rocust notification rules, I might not need this, but they do not seem to, and so I do need this.
But. I do not want to create a "PowerUp". Is this just a misunderstanding over unnecessarily strong branding. I am looking at the doc for creating api keys. It keeps stopping me at "go to your PowerUps", and such as that. I do not want a PowerUp. I want an ApiKey. What is the deal here?
Perhaps this might be related. I use the free tier. The system will be more usable if it had proper notification rules (or if I can make them with an API client), but I want to create a apikey to test things out before I sign up for a monthly charge.
If anyone is interested, I have a great "why does everything on the Internet cost $10 a month?" rant. :--)
